# Is R limited for matrix?

Tags: regression, cross-validation

I am using R to find the value of lambda by cross-validation for ridge regression but the problem is my code as follows does not work for such a big matrix. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance. My own work is

```
# X<- my own dataset which has n=205 observations by 18856 variables. 
I = diag(18856)
cv = 1.0e30   #arbitrary value
for (i in 1:100) { 
   lambdai = i/100*1 # value of lambda cvi = 0
   for (j in 1:n) {
      bR = solve( t(X[-j,]) %*% X[-j,] + lambdai*I) %*% (t(X[-j,]) %*% y[-j])
      yje = X[j,] %*% bR # fitted 
      values cvi = cvi +(yje-y[j])^2 
   }
if (cvi < cv) { 
cv = cvi 
lambda = lambdai 
}
```

}

Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: What version of R are you using?  R > 3.0.0 should have improved handling of large matrices.  Even so, 205 x 18856 doesn't seem particularly large.  How much RAM do you have in your machine?

Comment: I am using R> 3.0.1. And RAM is 4GB. Would that be enough? Thanks dear Russell.

Comment: mbq-I just want to know is there another way to compute large matrix in R or not?

Comment: What exactly is the error message you are getting?  Also some of your code appears to be in error, e.g. "values cvi" at the end of the j loop and the last line.  In addition, please use the formatR package and tidy.source before posting code.  Consider adjusting your question to make it more specific about the general aims you what to accomplish and their relevance to statistical issues.

Comment: Well, Russell, I have this error"Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.6 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In diag(18856) :
  Reached total allocation of 1535Mb: see help(memory.size)"
 when I want to create a diagonal matrix diag(18856) and also for all the other matrix.

Comment: And also there will be no error for small matrix!

Comment: The allocation of the 18856x18856 diagonal matrix is probably your issue.  seanv507's solution might get you going in the right direction because that matrix is very sparse.  Also you might want to search around the R packages some more, I know there are some out there specifically for ridge regression and if you use them you might be saved the effort of figuring out your own algorithm.

Comment: Do you use R 64-bit version or 32-bit? On my machine with 4Gb memory I=diag(18856) only work in 64-bit version of R.

Comment: Hello dear Gregory, I use 32-bit. Great clue thank you very much I am changing my version then and hope it will work. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your data is very sparse (vry few variables non zero in each observation)

you need to look for sparse data packages... eg see http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2011/10/31/using-sparse-matrices-in-r/